# Data Loads On Every Pan and Zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm adding JSON data to Google Maps based on the current bounding box (or viewport) of the map. The problem is that even the slightest pan or zoom redraws that data. How can I make it so once the data is loaded, it does not need to redraw (or reload)?

This is the event that I'm using:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
  if (map.getZoom() > 12) {
    bBox = getBB(); // get current bounding box
      $.ajax({
        url: '/getdata',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(bBox),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (ai) {
          addToMap(ai);
        }
     });
   } else {
     map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
       map.data.remove(feature);
     });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a two-fold solution would work: modify your method for choosing data to load to the map, and then loading the data after a brief time that the map is inactive.

Maybe add a delay between the `idle` event being fired and the map reloading the data. This could be accomplished by a global `setTimeout` that would be updated every time the map becomes idle.

```
var loadDelay = setTimeout(function(){},0);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){
  clearTimeout(loadDelay);
  loadDelay = setTimeout(function(args){old_function(args)}, delayTime); //choose time between idle and load
});
```

Also, you could chunk up your data into square regions, and check which regions inside the map bounds have already been loaded, and then not blit those to the map.

**EDIT**

To keep track of data will be a two-step process. First is to change the bounds you get for an individual query. Second is to keep an array of uniformly-sized areas that have already been load. Something like:

```
var loaded = [];
function load(bounds){
  var north = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
  var south = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
  var east = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
  var west = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
  for(var lat=parseFloat(south.toFixed(1)); lat<north; lat += 0.1){ //or some other interval
    for(var lng=parseFloat(west.toFixed(1)); lng<east; lng += 0.1){
      if(!(south+','+west in loaded)){
        import(south, west); //function to get and display information
        loaded.push(south+','+west);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some system like this should load parts of the data that have not already been loaded.

Comment: Hmm, ok I will try this. I guess my issue is how do I not load data for the last viewed bounding box. Even if you pan a little, it sends an updated bounding box.

Comment: Hopefully this will fix it. It basically kicks back the time that the data loads to map every time the map is updated.

Comment: Another key part of this is splitting up the data when you get the data from Ajax. Keep track of the data you already loaded, and choose your data based on that.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. But how do I keep track of the data that has already been loaded? Can I use something like localStorage for this?

Comment: When you say `import(south,west);`, does that mean I can remove that line and add my function there that loads the JSON data?

Comment: South, West are substitutes for some sort of bounds. This is all pseudoish code